# Jenkins: git clone over https not working

Tags: linux, github, jenkins, https, proxy

So, here's the problem:
I have a Jenkins instance on Linux behind a corporate firewall. I can clone repositories with *git://*, but when I try to use *https://*, I get

> The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing https://github...

I have connected to the Linux machine via SSH and have found that I was also not able to clone via https on the command line. However, I have managed to fix the proxy settings (by adding our corporate Github to *no_proxy*), so now it works on the command line - but I still get the same error in Jenkins.

What else can I do? Where does this weird behaviour come from? Is there anyone out there who can give me a hint on this problem?

(Using *git://* does not help since I also want to push to the repository. I guess I could also use *ssh://*, but I thought *https://* was the simpler solution... - Also, I would really like to know what's wrong here.)

Comment: `https://` and `git://` use auth with credentials whereas `ssh://` uses key auth. Most likely you do not provide proper credentials in your `https://` call? See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html)

Comment: I had some kind of the same problem with cloning git repositories with `https://` protocol. I had to set (like you did) my proxy but it wasn't sufficient. The last thing to do was (for me) to set in my `.gitconfig` the `sslVerify` parameter to `true` and the `sslCAInfo`. I do not remember of the returned error so it might be something else...

Comment: @fishi Since Github uses so-called 'smart' https, you do not need credentials for cloning, only for pushing. And in my case already the cloning fails.

Comment: To my knowledge `https://` cloning without credentials only works for public repos. As soon as you want to clone a private repo you would need to provide credentials - also in the 'smart'-https version. Anyways you are right that this is most likely not the issue, since the server throws a 503 and not a 403.